# A Word Related to Books that begins with the letter R

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently coding items for my game and I thought of a really funny one, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the final word should be. Here's what I'm thinking:

The item goes in the trinket slot of the character page, and it looks like a book. I wanted to have each word of the book name spell out "Too Long Didn't Read". Here's what I came up with off the top of my head:

"Tildra's Lost Dragon ______"

I was thinking the last word should be related to a Tome, Bestiary, or Manuscript; but I'm at a loss for words that start with 'R' that could finish this item name. Are there any words at all that could fill the blank? Even an archaic one?

Comment: Reference, record, register, report, registry, report, review, revelation, reader (like primer), roll (like scroll), etc

Comment: Review, register, report, record

Comment: @DanBron Excellent! Put your comment into an answer.

Comment: I'm doing "Tildra's Lost Dragon Report". It somehow makes it even more funny.

Comment: [Rescript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[record](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/record)***

> A thing constituting a piece of evidence about the past, especially an
>   account kept in writing or some other permanent form.

(Oxford)

Also you might consider Dan Bron's commented suggestions:

> reference, register, report, registry, review, revelation, reader,
>   roll (scroll).

Comment: Copy Dan Bron's suggestions and I'll choose your answer. I guess he didn't want to.

Comment: I didn't see them until now, all decent choices too.

Comment: @Gary Take them all, with my blessing, and my +1.

Answer (score 4):

There is the booklet for school children, which is the "reader"